# How is this situation handled in microservices?

Tags: .net-core, cloud, microservices

We are getting started with microservices and looking into events and inter service communication and are wondering how the following (if it occurs) would be handled.

**Scenario**

Our services are running on aws with autoscaling set up.  This means in most cases we will have at least 2 instances running exact same service to handle load.  The load balancer will do its job and pass the requests to the instances depending on traffic.

**Questions**

1. Lets say there is a service on server1 listening for events and due to load its autoscalled.  Now there are 2 copies of the same service listening for the same event. For example OrderCompletedEvent.  How/what is the way this is handled in terms of who picks up the event first?
2. As they are both listening for the same event will this create a race condition?

Did a few searches online and was not able to find anything maybe have not got the right terminology to search so would appreciate being pointed in the right direction of what to look for.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessageDispatcher.html and https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/CompetingConsumers.html. These are basically your choices here.

Comment: @tomredfern That looks interesting appreciate it will take a look.